# ajaxToolkit PopupControlExtender not working. Outdated?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, popupcontrolextender

I'm followed [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/display-gridview-row-details-using-asp-net-ajax-popup-control) but I'm getting runtime error when `mouseover`:

> Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined. Parameter
>   name: type

The problem is in this lines of code:

```
string OnMouseOverScript = string.Format("$find('{0}').showPopup();", behaviorID);
string OnMouseOutScript = string.Format("$find('{0}').hidePopup();", behaviorID); 

img.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", OnMouseOverScript); 
img.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", OnMouseOutScript);
```

Any thoughts on this?  My goal is to get details of `gridview row` when `mouseover` a specific column, like the demo on the referenced linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by updating AJAX Control Toolkit to it's last version (v15.1 from March 2015)!